# Get result of value_count() to excel from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `"df"` with a column called `"column1"`. By running the below code:

```
df.column1.value_counts()
```

I get the output which contains values in column1 and its frequency. I want this result in the excel. When I try to this by running the below code:

```
df.column1.value_counts().to_excel("result.xlsx",index=None)
```

I get the below error:

> *AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_excel'*

How can I accomplish the above task?

Comment: Well to_excel only works on data frames. I would send your results to a separate data frame and then call to_excel

Comment: pd.DataFrame(df.column1.value_counts()).to_excel("result.xlsx",index=None)

Comment: @Merlin Well I am getting the the output in an excel, but its incomplete output. There are two parts to the output. A list of Names and the frequency for each name. Using the code given by you, I only get frequency part in the output. Names are missing

Comment: Series have a method `.to_frame()`, so you could also do `df.column1.value_counts().to_frame().to_excel("result.xlsx")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `index = None`, You need the index, its the name of the values.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.column1.value_counts()).to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

If go through the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) `Series` had no method `to_excel`it applies only to `Dataframe`.
So either you can save it another frame and create an excel as:

```
a=df.column1.value_counts()
a.to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Look at [Merlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575246/get-result-of-value-count-in-excel-in-pandas#38575246) comment I think it is the best way:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.column1.value_counts()).to_excel("result.xlsx")
```

Comment: Well I am getting the the output in an excel, but its incomplete output. There are two parts to the output. A list of Names and the frequency for each name. Using the code given by @Merlin, I only get frequency part in the output. Names are missing

Comment: @user6461192 you are passing index as `None` remove it,because the list of names are in index .